# Xcode doesn't detect text being typed (UI Testing)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

Ok,

So I'm running a UI test where I'm learning as I go along. In the test there's a segment of code where I select a text field, hit the "Clear text" button, enter some text and then hit "Done" on the keyboard:

```
XCUIElement *textField = [app.tables.cells.textFields element];
XCTAssertTrue(textField.exists, "Text field couldn't be found");

// Clear the text field
[textField.buttons[@"Clear text"] tap];
XCTAssertTrue([textField.value length] == 0, @"The text field wasn't cleared.");

// Type in new data
[textField typeText:@"New Device"];
XCTAssertTrue([textField.value length] > 0, @"The text field is empty.");
NSString *textFieldValue = textField.value;
XCTAssertTrue([textFieldValue isEqualToString:@"New Device"], @"Strings do not equate.");

// Save
[app.keyboards.buttons[@"Done"] tap];
```

Seems like this should be a simple test but there are a few problems I'm running into:

1. When running the test, though I tell it to type "New Device" for some reason it always types in "now Device" with the lowercase "n". The XCTAssert statement checking the textfield's value always fails unless I instruct the text to type in "now Device", which it does without issue (WTF!?).
2. After hitting the "Done" button, only the word "now" remains in the textfield. The word "Device" is completely missing. This is a problem since there's code under the hood that checks if the string is at least 5 characters.

I'm at my wits end since there isn't much documentation on UI Testing in Xcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the focus definitely on the text field when you begin typing? Try `[textField tap]` before any calls to `typeText:`.

Comment: I had the same thought and tried doing a `tap` before `typeText` but that doesn't help. The text field is definitely in focus though.

Comment: I've had this same issue in my iOS app which uses a stock search field. Although I try to record a tap event followed by a typeText event, only the tap is automatically generated. After I record the tap event, I edit the test manually to include a typeText instruction on the same element.

Comment: Luckily for me the problem seemed to resolve itself. Guessing it was a bug in Xcode?